# Construct triangle ABC, denote I as the incenter, A' as the mid point of the arc BC of the circumcircle. Show that A'B = A'C = A'I

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles, quadrilateral

I know angles BAC and BCA are equal since the arcs BA and AC are equal however I do not know where to go on from there. Hints or answers involving cyclic quadrilaterals would be appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: The center ? the incenter, the circumcenter, the orthocenter or the mittenpunkt ?

Comment: `triangle ABC` If you mean *equilateral* triangle $\triangle ABC$ then you should edit that into the question.

Comment: @dxiv You are right It must be an equilateral triangle then all the central points concur. But I am not sure how the question should be worded to remove the ambiguity caused by not saying exactly which center the OP is talking about.

Comment: I edited the problem, sorry about that! @dxiv

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit The question does not state anything about it being equilateral, why is it obvious that it is?, thanks

Comment: @dxiv So how would the proof look if it was given that the triangle is equilateral? Sorry for the miscommunication, the question given just lacks information.

Comment: @dxiv angle BAA' = angle AA'C because AA' is the triangle's interior angle bisector. Denote BAA' as theta. Since BIC is the central angle, it would equate to 4 theta. Now angle BIA = 2 theta. How do I prove that angle IBA' is 2 theta as well? Or am I just confusing myself and it is much simpler than this.

Comment: @Bananaman `Since BIC is the central angle` No, it's not the *central* angle unless the incenter coincides with the circumcenter (which only happens if the triangle is equilateral). See my answer, instead.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: since $A'$ is the midpoint of arc $BC$, it follows that $AA'$ is the bisector of $\angle BAC\,$, so the points $A, I, A'$ are collinear. Let $B'$ be the intersection of bisector $BI$ with the circumscribed circle.

Then:

- $\angle IBA' = \angle CBA'+ \angle IBC = \frac{\angle BAC}{2}+\frac{\angle ABC}{2}$ by the [inscribed angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle) properties;
- $\angle BIA'= \frac{1}{2} \left(\text{arc}\, A'B + \text{arc}\, AB'\right) = \frac{\angle BAC+\angle ABC}{2}$ by the [secant angle](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/SecantAngle.shtml) theorem.

Therefore $\angle IBA' = \angle BIA'\,$, so $\triangle IBA'$ is isosceles, so $A'B=A'I\,$. It follows in a symmetric way that $A'C=A'I\,$ which completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

The proof of the following fact is simple enough and hence is skipped.

In $\triangle ABC$, if I is the in-center, AI (the angle bisector of $\angle A$), when extended will meet the perpendicular bisector of $BC$ at A’. A’ will lie on the circum-circle of $\triangle ABC$. In short, AIA’ is a straight line and A’BAC is cyclic.

[image]

It should be clear that $\angle 1= \angle2$ and $\angle 3 =\angle 4$. Note also that $\angle 4 = \angle 5$.

$\angle A’IB =\angle 2 + \angle 3 = … = \angle A’BI$.

.. .. ..

Remark:- The circum-center is O, NOT I.